# function call not working on javascript events

Tags: javascript, function, events

Here is my code where i call function focused():

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Question:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="qtitle" placeholder="Title" value="<?php echo set_value('user_name'); ?>" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Option A:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="optiona" name="optiona" onkeyup="focused()" placeholder="Option A" value="<?php echo set_value('user_name'); ?>" />
                <input type="file" class="form-control" id="img_option1" name="offerimg1" placeholder="Option A" value="<?php echo set_value('user_name'); ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="prduct_id" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('cpid'); ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Option B:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="optionb" name="optionb" placeholder="Option B" value="<?php echo set_value('user_name'); ?>" />
                <input type="file" class="form-control" id="img_option2" name="offerimg2" placeholder="Option B" value="<?php echo set_value('user_name'); ?>" />
            </div>
```

and the script here:

```
function focused()
{
document.getElementById('img_option1').style.visibility = "hidden"; 
}
```

Its not calling the function, I tried onclick, onfocus,etc

when I give style="visibility:hidden" inline (inside id img_option1) it is hiding the element.

please help

Comment: Where exactly is that script placed?

Comment: Seems to work just fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/yoahk4pa/

Comment: Yeah...It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/p1fjbgcy/

Comment: So no error in code? I don't know why it is not working in my system?

Comment: the script is placed inside script tag  at the bottom of the same page